# Problems of political philosophy?

Tags: political-philosophy

Are there any resources or references that concisely state the problems with political philosophy?  Recommended texts for beginners are also welcome!

Comment: Seems pretty similar to this? http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/how-can-i-start-learning-about-political-philosophy?rq=1

Comment: Can you say more? Is there some research you've done?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a number of obvious ones:

- Proper role of state vs. individuals
- How is property allocated by/within a state?
- Proper role between states
- Proper source of authority/legitimacy of a government
- How to structure a government
- Source of individual rights in a government (do they come from God? from the government? from some other place?)
- Correct model for law (theological? utilitarian?)
- The correct role of law (should it be codified? or should it be more flexibly determined by whoever leaders are?)

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting political philosophy books:

"The Open Society and Its Enemies" by Karl Popper.

"Liberalism: In the Classical Tradition" by Ludwig von Mises.

"The Structure of Liberty" and "Restoring the Lost Constitution" by Randy Barnett.

"Atlas Shrugged", "Capitalism: The Unknown Ideal" and "The Virtue of Selfishness" by Ayn Rand.

"The Machinery of Freedom" by David Friedman.